# Postgres simultaneously insert same data from 2 different connections

Tags: postgresql, authentication, sql-insert

I am implementing an authentication system, and while doing so it struck me if there are two servers (for load balancing) connecting to one DB. The table has an email field marked unique, if they both insert NewUser(user data is same for both) at the same time, will DB be populated with 2 NewUser or there will be a collision. How to tackle this.

There is no code sample as it's just a thought in my mind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the email column is defined as unique, the second insert will result in an error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the insert transaction will be from 2 different connections hitting at the exact moment. will it still be through error ?

Comment: Read this [Transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) and if it does not answer your question or you have a  more specific question after reading it, then update your question.